# How to create aura lightning page to help me visualize data in separate pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, component

I have an aura component lightning page with many fields in it.

To avoid having too long scrolling I need to separate and visualize the fields in different pages.

Is there any lightning component to help me separate and create different pages?

If not could you please suggest any workaroud or example of how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<lightning:tabset>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabset) and [`<lightning:tab>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/example) allow you to create a tabbed interface, which would be an appropriate use case here.